# Mongoose : aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB) on Mongodb v3.4.6

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a database where total records are approx 70k. My query is a aggregate query which currently having 2 pipelines including sort operation. 
The query is

```
var ObjQuery = { warehouseId: '59d62a43fb452a0f0ba422ba', timeCreated: {'$gte': 1507288594 }}

var pipeline = [{'$match': ObjQuery}, {'$sort': {'timeCreated': 1}}];

var aggregation = itemStoreModel.aggregate(pipeline).allowDiskUse(true);

aggregation.exec(function (err, result) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    else
        res.json({data: result, message: 'Operation Successful.', status: 'success', statusCode: '201'});
});
```

This query gives me following error

```
error: uncaughtException: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB) date=Mon Oct 16 2017 16:18:23 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), pid=16328, uid=null, gid=null, cwd=c:\NODE\avancer\avancer-warehouse, execPath=C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe, version=v6.0.0,
```

I did a lot more work around to solve this issue over the net but all i found were the issues regarding the mongodb version <=2.6. There might be a case where this issue may not occur in mongodb v3.4.6. Is there anything i am missing in the aggregation?

Views are welcome.

Comment: Which mongoose version? What does the console show when you use `mongoose.set('debug', true)` in your listing to log operations? What you are looking for is the presence of `{ cursor: { } }` in the issued options to aggregate. Because if it's not there, then that is the problem.

Comment: @Neil Lunn Its mongoose@4.9.2

Comment: It should be adding the cursor option, albeit actually behind the scenes. What happens if you remove the `.allowDiskUse(true)`? Or did you add that because you were seeing the error. Are you certain of the server version? If you are not sure, then log in using the `mongo` shell and type `db.version()` which actually shows you the server version.

Comment: I actually cannot reproduce this one. Admittedly when trying to pin the mongoose version to 4.9.2, the problem appears to be that mongoose itself does not pin the mongodb driver version, so the latest 2.2.x release is always being installed. Thus, without explicitly adding the cursor option I get a different error, related to the cursor option being required. You could force usage of the cursor option and the `.toArray()` method from the underlying driver, but the most simple case appears to be upgrading mongoose. Current 4.12.2 means your quite a few versions back.

Comment: Did find the solution for this?? Even I tried { allowDiskUse: true }, not solved my problem yet??